# Just Installed 11.10 on a PC that had problems with 9 - First Run, Screens going black

Tags: 11.10, drivers, nvidia, screen

Last time I had ubuntu on this PC the screen would go black every few seconds and stay black for a bit, that was running 9, now I've upgraded to 11.10 hoping that would fix the issue, but the issue still seems to remain, only it's not as bad as it was with 9.

I can at least ask for help this time around.   But anyway it's clearly something wrong with the graphics card ( NVIDIA GT 240 ) I had to use nomodeset so that I could install properly, and I want to know if I should grab the drivers off of jockey, or grab them directly from nvidia.

I installed 11.10 on a laptop with Radeon HD 6700M graphics a couple of days a go, and I had a hell of a time getting openGL to work.  I had to download the catalyst driver from radeon, purge the drivers jockey gave me, start up without graphics and install the ATI drivers that way.

I speak too soon, it's still going black on and off..  Gonna try a restart... 
I'd rather not go through that bloody hassle again.  Based on my experience with the radeon 12 hours ago: getting the drivers from NVIDIA, starting up without xorg, purging the drivers that are there and planting the NVIDIA drivers in will be what I need to do: unless some one has a simpler way that isn't going to tank my nice fresh install, but if there's no nicer way, please let me know what packages I'm going to need to purge.

It's not blacking out now... But I still don't trust it.   Going to install chrome because I can trust it's about://gpu data to tell me if my gfx card is working fully or not.

GLTron is running, so openGL that's a good sign, and jockey just jumped up and said it's activated a recommended driver - looks like I was fretting over nothing.  This driver seems to work so I'll stick with it.  Might as well ask what I wanted to ask next since I've wasted a post.

Is 12.04 any good or should I wait to see a video walkthrough before I upgrade?  I'm really digging 11.10 here.  Awesome alt-tab and workspace flow.  I was a doubter of full screen apps but I'm not anymore, after 2 days of unity/11.10

Comment: I've got an update on the problem. Upgraded to 12.04, and it happens when I use the tty, or when I open terminal. I'll just check that once more.... Yep, seems to have no problems whatsoever as long as the terminal isn't open. Is there a compatibility mode I can use for the terminal. Or a way to change whatever settings that are messing with my monitor/card (maybe a refresh rate?)

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a hardware problem. It's happening more and more frequently and seems to happen independent of the Ubuntu version you are using.

You may need to replace your video card.